# call sharepoint 2010 webpart methods

Tags: sharepoint

I am creating a SharePoint site through visual studio and I created a user control(ascx).I have written some methods on user control code behind file(axcs.cs). How can I call those methods through jquery ajax since methods on ascx.cs cannot be called by jquery ajax directly? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot call a control's server methods from javascript (jquery/ajax).

However, depending on the logic that needs to be called you have options. For one, you can create a *.ashx handler that will handle requests from you javascript code and call server-side logic.